# NSUserDefaults for all uses

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsuserdefaults, preferences

currently I'm using per user defaults.

```
_defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
...
NSData *myData = [_defaults valueForKey:key];
```

However, I need an equivalent where I can save global data to be shared by all users and not just the current user.

What is the equivalent is `NSUserDefaults` for all users ?

Comment: what you mean all users? there are many users using a single app in the same device? or?

Comment: I refer to the case where a single app may run by multiple users. For each run, it may load/save data into a global space to be accessible for all other users that may run this application. The question is whether NSdefaults is helping here, or that I should use another approach ? thanks !

Comment: I would suggest against using NSUserdefaults for multiple users on a single app. You should save your data for each user in documents folder instead. Format of data, depends on how much data you have, if not much, you can get away with xml format, or if there are a lot of data per user, you should really consider coredata.

Comment: NSUserDefaults is designed per user.  Core Foundation has support for app level preferences.  If the shared data is large, you may want to use CoreData.

Comment: @Jerry, can you show me an example for app level preferences ?

Comment: Look in Preferences Programming Topics for Core Foundation.  There is a family of methods prefixed by `CFPreferences` to access preferences at a lower level than provided by NSUserDefaults.